# Using ogr2ogr w/ -s_srs to combine inconsistent EPSG files into PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, shapefile, coordinate-system, convert

I'm having trouble combining shapefiles from TIGER and different local governments into a single postgis db to query legislative locations.  I've imported all data to multipolygon geom, but found some datasets' polygon shapes returning really large floats values lat/lng.  Looking more closely, I noticed inconsistent EPSG coordinate systems, based on searching prj2epsg.org with contents of my .prj files:

```
#Census Data (EPSG:4269 - GCS_North_American_1983)    
GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]

#Texas Data (EPSG:3081 - NAD_1983_Lambert_Conformal_Conic)
PROJCS["NAD_1983_Lambert_Conformal_Conic",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",1000000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",1000000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-100.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",34.91666666666666],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",27.41666666666667],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",31.16666666666667],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

I can't seem to get ogr2ogr to explicitly transform the target coordinate systems with `-a_srs EPSG:3081 -s_srs EPSG:3081 -t_srs EPSG:4269`:

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"host=..." file.shp -nlt MULTIPOLYGON -s_srs EPSG:3081 -a_srs EPSG:3081 -s_srs EPSG:3081 -t_srs EPSG:4269 -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=the_geom -nln table_name.
```

I've tried a number of different variations on the above, but at best I get `ERROR 1: AddGeometryColumn failed for layer table_name, layer creation has failed`.

**What am I missing here?**

I'm still a bit of a novice on work with shapefiles.

Example source files:

- From Texas: ftp://ftpgis1.tlc.state.tx.us/DistrictViewer/House/PLANH309.zip
- From Tiger: ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2013/CD/tl_2013_us_cd113.zip

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Can you confirm some things: you have source data from two spatial reference systems (SRSs): EPSG:4269 & EPSG:3081, and your desired SRS (in PostGIS) is EPSG:4269?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're overcomplicating the use of SRS flags.

If you have source data from two spatial reference systems (SRSs): EPSG:4269 (Census data) and EPSG:3081 (Texas data), and your desired SRS (in PostGIS) is EPSG:4269 (same as Census data), then you'd use two variations of the `ogr2ogr` command.

For the Texas data, specify source and target SRSs, so data are reprojected:

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"...." texas.shp -nlt MULTIPOLYGON -s_srs EPSG:3081 -t_srs EPSG:4269 -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=the_geom -nln tex_table_name
```

For Census data, just assign it (in case it's not already assigned), without projection:

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"host=..." census.shp -nlt MULTIPOLYGON -a_srs EPSG:4269 -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=the_geom -nln cen_table_name
```

Comment: In the end the issue wound up being that I had an older version of postgis and my spatial_refs were out of date.